# Error when using Rscript but no error when sourcing R file

Tags: r, data.table, rscript

I am using a R file to read a lot of csv files. I use `fread` to read the files. The program is OK when I source the file, but I got error when using `R -f filename` or using `Rscript filename`. Sometimes it prompts

> .   `Error in UseMethod("conditionCall") :`

and sometimes it prompts

> .    `Error reading file`

Why are there errors when using these command lines?

Comment: Please share the script in question.

Comment: Most likely a problem with encoding of the file - try to prepare a test file with no special characters.

Comment: `ReadCustomer = function(x)
  {
    cat("Reading", x, "\n")
    if (!file.exists(x)) return()
    OutFile = sprintf("../../../../tmp/%s", unzip(x, exdir = "../../../../tmp"))
    fread(OutFile, encoding = "UTF-8", select = c("customer_sysno", "event_cat2")) %>%
      filter(event_cat2 == "***") %>%
      select(CustomerSysNo = customer_sysno) %>%
      mutate(CustomerSysNo = as.numeric(CustomerSysNo)) %>%
      filter(CustomerSysNo > 0) %>%
      fwrite("../../data/exp3_users.csv", append = T, col.names = F, quote = F)
    file.remove(OutFile)
  }
  
  lapply(Name, ReadCustomer)`

Comment: My code is as above and `Name` is a vector of csv names.

Comment: In addition, would it be OK to run it on Linux server?